# I can't delete or restore a record on composite primary key

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have model with the following primary key

```
use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;
protected $table = 'requests';
protected $primaryKey = ['request_id', 'user_id'];
public $incrementing = false;
protected $keyType = 'string';

protected $fillable = [
    'request_id',
    'user_id',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'deleted_at',
];
```

and I run the controller of the following

```
   public function store(int $request) {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $Request = Request::withTrashed()->firstOrCreate([
            'request_id' => $request,
            'user_id' => $user->id,
        ]);

        if (!$Request->wasRecentlyCreated) {
            $Request->deleted_at ? $Request->restore() : $Request->delete();
        }
    
    }
```

and everytime I run the controller I get error of

```
LOG.error: Illegal offset type { "userId": 1, "exception": {} }
```

why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eloquent does not support composite keys:

> Eloquent requires each model to have at least one uniquely identifying "ID" that can serve as its primary key. "Composite" primary keys are not supported by Eloquent models.

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#composite-primary-keys

Comment: is it a common practice to have a id primary key even if it is not needed or is it just laravel condition?

Comment: Laravel assumes multiple things, incl. i.e. table names, column names etc. It's sometime the case that bending such assumptions can be problematic or not even supported. The problem is in Eloquent that does not deal with primary composite keys. Is it worth bothering really? It's up to you to decide, but I'd say that it'd be much simpler, faster and cheaper to just create that column to make it happy and not use it than tinker around for hours.to end up with some sort of work-arounds. You can always get back to this if nothing better is on the plate, but don't make it your blocker.

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around by adding this line to the Model

```
protected function setKeysForSaveQuery($query) {
        foreach ((array) $this->primaryKey as $key) {
            $query->where($key, '=', $this->original[$key] ?? $this->$key);
        }

        return $query;
    }
```

it seems it causes a lot of errors sometimes but it works fine for me now

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Eloquent does not make things easier to the developer all the time. It is only another way to manage data, especially for those who struggle writing SQL statements appropriately and with good performance results.

In order to delete a row with a composite primary key, here is an easy approach (regardless of your model class definition).

You don't need to add an auto incremented column to your tables if they already have a "natural" unique key. Creating an additional int/bigInt column for this purpose is overkilling and consumes more resources unnecessarily.

In this example the table **category** has a key defined as `[catId, userId]`.

In my JS file, the request is made like so:

```
axios.delete(`/category/${catId}/${userId}`)
```

I am using axios for simplicity, but you could use the fetch API, jQuery, Alpine or whatever you like.

The method in my controller file:

```
   public function destroy($catId, $userId) {
      $result = $this->category->destroy($catId, $userId);
      return $result;
   }
```

The method in my model class:

```
   /**
    * Marks the row, with the given key, as deleted.
    * 
    * @param int $catId  The category id.
    * @param int $userId  The user id.
    */
   public function destroy($catId, $userId) {
      $this->userId = $userId;
      $this->categoryId = $catId;
      $query = "UPDATE category SET deleted = 'Y' WHERE userId = ? AND categoryId = ?";
      return DB::delete($query, [$this->userId, $this->categoryId]);
   }
```

My route is defined as follows:

```
Route::delete('/category/{catId}/{userId}', [categoryController::class, 'destroy']);
```

The model class method only marks the row as deleted (soft deletes managed on my own for I don't like Laravel way). This code is actually working as expected.

I hope this example may be helpful to anyone.